# how can I assign metadata through a flow? // after save record triggered flow

Tags: visual-workflow, case, metadata, recordtriggeredflow, after

Hi how are you? I have a problem, I am migrating a process builder to flow in the Case object. The problem arises with a decision in which it enters if the following conditions are met:

AND(
ISCHANGED([Case].OwnerId ),
OR(
[Case].RecordType.Name = "Reclamos". ,
[Case].RecordType.Name = "Consultas".
),
OR(
[Case].Owner:Queue.DeveloperName = "Celula_1",
[Case].Owner:Queue.DeveloperName = "Celula_2"
)
[image: conditions of entry]

When the result matches "Celula_1", it goes the way of true and then performs the following filter:

Field: Owner Id.
Operator: Equals
Type: Formula
Value: $CustomMetadata.Cola__mdt.Emi_sin_material.Queue_id__c

When the filter is true it updates the next record:

Field: Cell
Type: Picklist
Value: Emi sin material
[image]

When the result matches "Celula_2", it goes the way of true and then performs the following filter:

Field: Owner Id.
Operator: Equals
Type: Formula
Value: $CustomMetadata.Queue__mdt.Discapacidad.Queue_Id__c
[image]

In the flow I tried to replicate it in the form:

An element that gets records from the "Group" object, I add as a filter the condition:

Field: DeveloperName
Operator: Equals
Value: Celula_1

OR

Field: DeveloperName
Operator: Equals
Value: Celula_2
[image]

Then I add a decision element in which I add the following condition:

In the path of Cell 1:
Resource: $Record > Owner ID
Operator: Equals
Value: $CustomMetadata.Cola__mdt.Emi_sin_material.Id_of_tail__c

In the Cell 2 path:
Resource: $Record > Owner ID
Operator: Equals
Value: $CustomMetadata.Cola__mdt.Discapacidad.Queue_Id__c
[image]

My problem is that I am doing the CustomMetadata value assignment wrong I would appreciate if you can help me with the picture. Greetings and thanks in advance, I attach images.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please could you [edit] the question to clarify just exactly what type of flow this is. I'm getting the feeling it's an after save record triggered flow from the tags, but would appreciate confirmation in the text. Is this actually updating the triggering record(s) or some other record(s)? If you are updating the triggering record(s), could you do this as a before save record triggered flow?

Comment: Hi Phil thanks for your prompt reply, it is indeed a record triggered flow that is executed after a record is created or updated in the Case object.

Comment: Can you not use a before save?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not *completely* sure this is the problem, because it's not in your screenshots, but I would open up your "Emi sin material" and "Tramites con material" actions:
[image: Update Records example partial screenshot]

If you want to actually *change* any records (at least, without having a lot of additional logic in previous actions), you need to be picking the highlighted option instead of the (default) first option.
Then you can fill in the records you want to change ("ID equals {!Record.Id}", for example; that's the same as "update triggering record"), the fields on those records you want to change, and the values you want to change those fields to.